# sudo not working in centOS 6.9 server

Tags: linux, hosting, sudo, centos6

I am accessing my server (centOS 6.9 (hostgator)) through SSH. When i use `sudo` command within PuTTY i get the following error

> sudo: effective uid is not 0, us sudo installed setuid root

why is this error occurring and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct permissions for sudo binary should include sticky-bit for owner.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
---s--x--x 1 root root 123832 Nov 24  2016 /usr/bin/sudo
```

To improve it you could do from root user:

```
chmod 4111 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Comment: i have the exact same permissions as you have posted on my server but i still get the same error

Comment: Dear @Naveed,  check that the owner of /usr/bin dir is root.
chown root:root /usr/bin

Comment: found what the problem was hostgator doesn't provide root access or sudo to shared hosts

Comment: you need to login via ssh with non-root user, then via `su -` become root.

Comment: is it like `su- root` whats the exact command i need to execute

Comment: `su - root` , then enter root password.

Comment: there is no root access or password

Comment: You need to get root password or set new password for root. How to change root password for centos6 is very popular question, you may easy find the answer, for example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35929/how-can-we-change-root-password)

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as root user? It looks like your OS has forced to use sudo with User ID 0 only which is the ID of root user.